# How to open file in thymeleaf onclick button?

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I have this code but it's displaying as white label error with just the url, not the pdf file itself: [http://localhost:8081/src/main/webapp/img/pdf/夢の街様にて検討中.pdf](http://localhost:8081/src/main/webapp/img/pdf/%E5%A4%A2%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%97%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6%E6%A4%9C%E8%A8%8E%E4%B8%AD.pdf)

```
<input type="button" value="Open pdf" onClick="window.open('../src/main/webapp/img/pdf/夢の街様にて検討中.pdf')">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<a href="/img/pdf/夢の街様にて検討中.pdf" target="_blank">
```